# Thumbnail wouldn't scale to size properly

Tags: php, loop, post-thumbnails

So I have a loop to display posts content, thumbnail, and the title.

```
<?php
echo "<div class='post-container'>";

   while ($p->have_posts()) {
     $p->the_post();
     $p->the_content();



     <div class="post">
       <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-news');
  }; ?>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     </div>





     <?php
   }
   echo "</div>";
}

 ?>
```

My functions page contains these statements:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'thumbnail-news', '384', '256', true );
```

But one of the two thumbnails is unsized. 
[image]

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you regenerate the thumbnails after creating your custom size?

Comment: Steve, thanks. I installed the regenerate thumbnail plugin, activated it, used it under tools, and it worked!